# How to sign debug apk for testing?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, travis-ci, android-testing

**Situation:**

- Android Project, open source, with possibly variable number of contributors.
- Strict testing (using travis-ci) for each PR.
- Uses Firebase auth and Google sign-in APIs.

Firebase requires SHA1 keys to be added while generating `google-services.json` file for the APIs to work. SHA1 of signing certificate of every computer is different. So, how should this situation be handled for testing?

*We might add SHA1 of each contributor's certificate, however it wont work for the travic-ci's pc, since it changes each time.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `debug.keystore` from one pc to repo

Add to build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('../debug.keystore')
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this safe, considering this is an open source project?

Comment: @rushi Yes, it is safe to put *debug* keystore in repo.

Comment: Ok, I'm believing you!